# Python 3: formatting zip module arguments correctly (newb)

Tags: python, zip

Please tell me why this code fails.  I am new and I don't understand why my formatting of my zip arguments is incorrect.  Since I am unsure how to communicate best so I will show the code, the error message, and what I believe is happening.

```
#!c:\python30
# Filename: backup_ver5.py

import os
import time
import zipfile


source = r'"C:\Documents and Settings\Benjamin Serrato\My Documents\python\backup_list"'

target_dir = r'C:\Documents and Settings\Benjamin Serrato\My Documents\python\backup_dir'

today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d') 

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

comment = input('Enter a comment --> ')

if len(comment) == 0:
    target = '"' + today + os.sep + now + '.zip' + '"'
else:
    target = '"' + today + os.sep + now + '_' + \
    comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip' + '"'

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)
    print('Successfully created directory', today)


print(target)
print(source)
zip_command = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w').write(source)

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Successful backup to', target)
else:
    print('Backup FAILED')

    enter code here
```

I recieve this error message:

```
Enter a comment -->
"C:\Documents and Settings\Benjamin Serrato\My Documents\python\backup_dir\20090
405\134614.zip"
"C:\Documents and Settings\Benjamin Serrato\My Documents\python\backup_list"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Benjamin Serrato\My Documents\python\backup_ve
r5.py", line 32, in <module>
    zip_command = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w').write(source)
  File "c:\python30\lib\zipfile.py", line 683, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, modeDict[mode])
  File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 222, in open
    closefd)
  File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 615, in __init__
    _fileio._FileIO.__init__(self, name, mode, closefd)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Benjamin Ser
rato\\My Documents\\python\\backup_dir\\20090405\\134614.zip"'
```

The two print tests before `zip_command` is assigned tell  me that the two strings are being passed to `zipfile.ZipFile()` correctly.  The traceback tells me I am not calling `zipfile.ZipFile()` correctly.  The error in `__init__` makes me more sure of this.  Last, the problem seems to be that I am causing my path string to have double backslashes.  I can't follow why the IOError shows that.

I used [this site](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/library/zipfile.html) to figure out how to use `zipfile`.  `zipfile` is a class, I import it at the start of the program then I use it and its primary method.  I pass the file I would like to write to `zipfile.ZipFile('file to write', 'mode')` and set the program to open an object set to be writable.  Then the command writes the file to the destination folder with a sub-method like so, `"".zipfile('files to write')`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not clear on which quotes you've removed and which you haven't; can you edit your post to show the current state of the code, and what error you're seeing now?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's because you have an extra pair of double quotes around your pathname. Remove the double quotes, and see if it works.

Comment: Right, I thought I needed to pass the quoted path to the command line when this was using an external program.  I removed the quotes since everything is already a string.  I removed the quotes from the if/else for the target string.  I still receive roughly the same error.

Comment: Did you try removing them from the source string as well?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other question: the double backslashes are there because they are [escaped](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Escape_sequences#Python).